# Mapping problem of PKCS11 EC public key to BC PKCS10 object

Tags: bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, pkcs11interop

I have created EC key pair in HSM using PKCS11Interop library, and i need to create PKCS10 Certificate request using this keys. For generation of PKCS10 I use BC, and in this situation i need to set public key as a parameter for PKCS10 request. 
In BC i need to get public key as ECPublicKeyParameters for putting in PKCS10 object. I do not know how to map PKCS11 public key to ECPublicKeyParameters.

Or may be there is another method for this type mapping?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Has the answer fixed your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PublicKeyFactory;

AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParameters = PublicKeyFactory.createKey(publicKey.getEncoded());
if (keyParameters instanceof ECPublicKeyParameters) {
    ECPublicKeyParameters ecPublicKeyParameters = (ECPublicKeyParameters) keyParameters;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which attributes of pkcs11 public key  must be used in yor code? I can get cka_ec_params, cka_ec_point from pkcs11 pub key. from these attributes how can i create a correct ecpublickeyparameters of BC?

Comment: I thought you already had a PublicKey object from your key pair generation. This is the publicKey object in my code. That's all.The call to PublicKeyFactory.createKey() already generates the ECPublicKeyParameters  object.